# chrome redirect after form submit

Tags: php, google-chrome

I'm struggling with this easy peace of code since 1 hour.
The problem occurs when I do a browser refresh after form submit.
Chrome browser wants to resubmit form. Every other browser work like expected.

Is there a workaround/hack that works in chrome?

```
<?php
// file: test.php
if(isset($_POST['test'])){
    header('Location: test.php');
    exit;
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="test" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: Try opening the page in new tab.

Comment: echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content='0;url=test.php'>";

Comment: is this on top of your page? did you send any content before setting the header?

Comment: If you add some random and useless query string parameter to the redirect url, chrome should treat it as another page. Not tested.

Comment: no there is no content before sending header. @user1950929 yes this works but I don't like the solution much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['test'])){
echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content='0;url=test.php'>";
exit();
}
?>
</head>
```

Comment: thanks.. @skrilled also posted this and it really works. Is this generally a better solution to `header`?

Comment: Didnt realize he posted it, but basically it is the standard html redirect, echoing it in php forces the browser to read it as it goes, basically the only real difference is that youre redirecting after page load as apposed to before

Comment: since I'm working with Zend Framework I thought I could use Zend's `redirector` action helper. But I think I'll write my own helper with `meta` tag. thanks